# Programatically logging in user in Symfony requires refresh

Tags: symfony

I'm using an event listener which does some validating and other stuff before everything else. One thing is to "internally" log in a user if there's a basic auth user (`PHP_AUTH_USER`) set.

In case the `PHP_AUTH_USER` is set an event is fired which logs you in:

```
private function authenticate()
{
    if($this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        return ;
    }

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
        $this->username, // = PHP_AUTH_USER
        $this->password,
        $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'),
        $this->user->getRoles()
    );

    $tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');
    $tokenStorage->setToken($token);

    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->req, $token);
    $this->container->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

    return true;
}
```

Back in my request listener I want to get the authenticated `user` object, but as long as I don't redirect (or refresh) the page the user is not really logged in (see below). So after my login event is fired I need to do this:

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
if( ! $user instanceof User) {
                    $event->setController(function() use (&$router) {
                        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('homepage'));
                    });
                }
```

Interestingly the `$user` variable here is just a string containing the user name. After the redirect everything it's an object.

The problem is that as long as I don't get an actual `User` object from `getUser` a lot of methods and routes are not working since they rely on getting a `User` object.

**Edit**: Fixed it by assigning the user object manually.

```
$userEntity = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['username' => $user]);
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->setUser($userEntity);
```

Comment: have you tried `$user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getRecord();` ?

Comment: Since getUser() returns a string `getRecord` would mean calling a function on a string. Tested it to be sure: `Call to a member function getRecord() on string`

Comment: when you create the token `UsernamePasswordToken` does it work if you use the user object and not the username in the token constructor. E.g.  do `$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($userObject, null, $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'), $userObject->getRoles());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [nehalist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3795530/nehalist), it was fixed by assigning the user object manually.

```
$userEntity = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['username' => $user]);
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->setUser($userEntity);
```